# sending two intents with a press of a button

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am creating my first app and I would like to know if it is possible to have two intents linked to a single button. My goal is: when the button is pressed it sends out an SMS and then makes a call, this is the call method which works I would like to know if there is a way to hard code an SMS and have it sent when the same button is pressed?

```
public void phone_call(View view) {
        String number = "123456789";
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            return;
        }
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, it is possible, use [`SmsManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager)

```
String number = "123456789";
String message = "some message";
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, null, null);
... rest of code and finally
startActivity(intent);
```

note you should have proper permission and also your app must be set as default SMS sender (only one app may send SMS, multiple apps can only receive/print them)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Comment: i got it to work thank you very much.  
        
        String number = "1234567890";
        String message = "Demo text";
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, null, null);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            return;
        }
        startActivity(intent);
    }